# Why backgroundTimeRemaining gives DBL_MAX even if application state is UIApplicationStateBackground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication, background-task

I am logging (writing into file) [backgroundTimeRemaining](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623029-backgroundtimeremaining) value each time my app is awoken from a suspended mode, right before I begin UIApplication's background task with expiration handler, like this (inside my method which makes a network request):

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground){

        [Logger logIntoFileNamed:@"log" withContent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" state %ld, background time remaining %.2f",(long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState],[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining ]] andPrettyTime:true];

        UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

            [app endBackgroundTask:task];
            task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

            [Logger logIntoFileNamed:@"log" withContent:@" expiration handler executed " andPrettyTime:true];
        }];
    }
```

According to docs, a value of `backgroundTimeRemaining` can be big if app is in the foreground:

> While the app is running in the foreground, the value in this property
>   remains suitably large.

But that is not a case here. My method is executed because application state is equal to `UIApplicationStateBackground`. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: Just checked... I am actually on `Thread 1` when this happens. Which should be the main thread (also when I run this code from `applicationDidEnterBackground:` it says `Thread 5`). The thing is, and I am not the one who wrote this part of a code, and I thought, since I am certain about the fact that app is woken from a suspended mode, that I am currently on a background thread executing all this...Have to investigate more and look into code, but if I am on a main thread, then I am getting normal results, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, According to docs:

> A value of backgroundTimeRemaining can be big if app is in the
>   foreground.

The `applicationDidEnterBackground` will need some time beetween states before providing the right `backgroundTimeRemaining`. That should start around ~180. Run it in an async thread with `dispatch_async` and filter out the Foreground values (>180).

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    {
        NSLog(@"Multitasking Supported");

        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
        background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {

            //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }];

        //To make the code block asynchronous
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //### background task starts
            NSLog(@"Running in the background\n");
            while(TRUE)
            {
                //#### Filter Foreground Values
                if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining] < 180) {
                    NSLog(@"Background time Remaining: %f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
                    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; //wait for 1 sec
                }

            }

            //#### background task ends
            //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
            [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
            background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Multitasking Not Supported");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a link where this is documented (about state switching delay) ? Also I use dispatch_async when executing a task,  I just left that because it is called in another method. Anyways, I tested a bit, and if I isolate the code and put it in an empty project inside of applicationDidEnterBackground: everything works as it should. The thing is, that this differs from my current setup. I run this code after the app is woken up from a suspended mode. In that case I get DBL_MAX value. Otherwise, it gives values < 180.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the way you are logging `backgroundTimeRemaining`. Try to put in after you obtain a background task:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
long appState = (long)app.applicationState;

if (appState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
   __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

     [app endBackgroundTask:task];
     task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
     [Logger logIntoFileNamed:@"log" withContent:@" expiration handler executed " andPrettyTime:true];
  }];

  NSTimeInterval backgroundTimeRemaining = app.backgroundTimeRemaining;
  [Logger logIntoFileNamed:@"log" withContent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" state %ld, background time remaining %.2f", appState, backgroundTimeRemaining] andPrettyTime:true];
}
```